# what does the phrase "Nothing you won't see in the hills" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

When asked about a place in a video game, the NPC gives this answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little guessing here, based on no context, but two answers spring to mind:

1) "If you go into those hills, you will see all sorts of (strange) stuff." (There is nothing you won't see in the hills.)

2) It could be that they were trying for a related idiom. "Nothing you wouldn't see on a farm/in the country." If they referring to an action/activity and not a specific place. IE, "Wow, there's two people having sex in the street." "Nothing you wouldn't see on a farm." (There's nothing here you wouldn't see in the hills.)